# Next.js commerce / React - useRouter in functional Component - dynamic header locale

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, shopify, commerce

I am fiddeling around with the Next.JS commerce framework.

In order to receive the correct translations I have to set a dynamic Accept-Language header in my graphql API request.
Routing and everything works well and I am getting the right translations when I set the header manually to es = spanish / en-US = english.

Here is my code:

```
import type { GraphQLFetcher } from '@commerce/api'
import fetch from './fetch'
import { API_URL, API_TOKEN } from '../../const'
import { getError } from '../../utils/handle-fetch-response'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const fetchGraphqlApi: GraphQLFetcher = async (
  query: string,
  { variables } = {},
  fetchOptions
) => {
  
  const { locale } = useRouter()
  console.log(locale)

  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    ...fetchOptions,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept-Language': 'es',
      'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': API_TOKEN!,
      ...fetchOptions?.headers,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables,
    }),
  })

  const { data, errors, status } = await res.json()

  if (errors) {
    throw getError(errors, status)
  }
  return { data, res }
}
export default fetchGraphqlApi
```

I would like to retrieve the locale with next/router which I am able to do in all my components.
When I try to do it in the above-posted code snipped I get the following error:

Server Error
**Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

I am confused. Is this not a functional component?
Why am I not able to call any hooks?

Any ideas how can I get this to work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React.js docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

> (This) function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element.

Your function is accepting multiple arguments, and is returning an object instead of a valid React element. That's why the hook is not recognizing your function as a functional component.